# avoiding multiple labels due to plot function inside for loop

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a code shown below,

```
for xe, ye in zip(x, y):
plt.scatter([xe] * len(ye), ye,color='green',edgecolor='black',zorder=2,label='OK')
```

Now this generates the label 'OK' everytime the for loop operates, which results in the picture below
[image]

I want to display a single label of "OK" instead of multiple. Please help!

Comment: don't put a plot inside a loop, instead pass a list of values to the plot.

Comment: could you explain little bit more about what 'passing list' means?

Comment: I'd recommend looking at a tutorial on how to plot things. If you have 3 points to plot, usually you do something like `plt.plot([1,2,3], [4,5,6])`  instead of making a loop and plotting each point individually